# How do I prevent the buttons from overlapping in Bootstrap4?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to separate the buttons and spread them horizontally. Currently, they are overlapping with each other ([Click here for the screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7MeS.png). I am using Bootstrap 4.

Here are some parts of my code:

```
<div class="container mt-3">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="btn-toolbar">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Select Movie
                </button>
                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Disney's Mulan</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Tenet</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Pinocchio</a>
                 </div>
            </div>


            <div class="col-md-6">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Select Movie
                </button>
                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Yellow Dhoby</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Yellow Vivo City</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Yellow Bedok</a>
                 </div>
            </div>

           <div class="col-md-12">
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Book Now</button>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I searched on similar questions. One guy mentioned to place them in btn-toolbar instead of btn-group as btn-group will combine them, but despite placing the buttons in btn-toolbar, it did not work.

Comment: Can you try to make a div after each "col" div with the style `clear: both;`?

Comment: Hi @klediooo, thank you for taking the time to answer this. I just tried that method but to no avail...

Comment: Why don't you add `m-1` class to the buttons! it will add `margin: 0.25rem !important;` to them from bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="container mt-3">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="btn-toolbar">
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-4">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Select Movie
                </button>
                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Disney's Mulan</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Tenet</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Pinocchio</a>
                 </div>
            </div>


            <div class="col-12 col-sm-4">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Select Movie
                </button>
                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Yellow Dhoby</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Yellow Vivo City</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Yellow Bedok</a>
                 </div>
            </div>

           <div class="col-12 col-sm-4">
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Book Now</button>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Do add Bootstrap 4 CDN
I think thats what you want